# Guardar GIF en base de datos PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Buenas tardes necesito algo de ayuda, lo que necesito es guardar un GIF en una base de datos postgreSQL.
Tengo una tabla llamada palabras la cual conta de 4 campos...

> palabra de tipo text 
> descripcion de tipo text
>  GIF de tipo text
>   recurso de tipo bytea

En la columna bytea debo guardar el GIF.
Estoy usando java para realizar esto.

Cuando mando a guardar el GIF seleccionado desde el programa que estoy desarrollando, se guarda correctaente en la base de datos. El problema radica en que cuando quiero recuperar ese dato y momstrarlo en un jlabel este se muestra como imagen y no como un GIF.

El código para guardar es el siguiente:

```
try {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO public.palabras(palabra, \"descripción\", gif, recurso) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
    String tipo, descrp, ruta;
    tipo = view.txt_tipo.getText();
    descrp = view.txt_desc.getText();
    ruta = ruta_archivo;
    PreparedStatement ps = c.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, tipo);
    ps.setString(2, descrp);
    ps.setString(3, tipo+".GIF");
    ps.setBinaryStream(4, fileInputStream, longitudByte);
    ps.execute();
    ps.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha guardado correctamente en la base de datos");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Controller_Guardar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Para recuperar uso el siguiente código:

```
String sql = "SELECT palabra, \"descripción\", gif, recurso FROM public.palabras WHERE palabra='" + view.text.getText() + "';";
System.out.println(sql);
ImageIcon foto;
InputStream inputStream;
String palabra;
String descripcion;
String gif;
try {
    ResultSet rs = c.Consulta(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
        palabra = rs.getString(1);
        descripcion = rs.getString(2);
        gif = rs.getString(3);
        inputStream = rs.getBinaryStream(4);

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        foto = new ImageIcon(bi);
        Image img = foto.getImage();
        byte[] ggg = getImageAsGIF(bi);
        ImageIcon iii = new ImageIcon(ggg);
        Icon Icono1 = new ImageIcon(iii.getImage().getScaledInstance(view.labelGifts.getWidth(), view.labelGifts.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        view.labelGifts.setIcon(Icono1);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos

Comment: por "gift" te refieres a [GIF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) ?

Comment: si jaja escribi mal, lo siento

Comment: =P  suele suceder, podes editar la pregunta así queda mas en contexto. yo la iba a editar pero luego me surgió la duda de si no sería un nuevo acrónimo o si se refería a almacenar imágenes de "regalos", por convención gif se escribe en mayúsculas  `GIF`

Comment: gracia por tu aporte, lo cambiare

Comment: mepa que el GIF tendrías que almacenarlo como `bytea`